# How to check current mouse button state using Win32/User32 library?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, mouse

I know how to stimulate clicks using User32 SendInput method and what I need is a similar User32 method but to obtain the current mouse button state.

Something similar to:

`public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);`

Function GetCursorPos gives me the current cursor position. What I need is the left button state (if it's clicked or not). Is there such a function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if Mouse LButton is down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275894/check-if-mouse-lbutton-is-down)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a method called GetAsyncKeyState. The method signature looks like this:

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode);`

Then you simply call it passing the left mouse key code (VK_LBUTTON = 0x01) and off you go.

More information directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: "Then you simply call it passing the left mouse key code (VK_LBUTTON = 0x01) and off you go."
This is really misleading.  You have to break up and analyze the returned short to create the state data.  This leaves the answer for this question somewhat incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

Use [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx), To Quote MSDN:

> The GetAsyncKeyState function works
>   with mouse buttons. However, it checks
>   on the state of the physical mouse
>   buttons, not on the logical mouse
>   buttons that the physical buttons are
>   mapped to. For example, the call
>   GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) always
>   returns the state of the left physical
>   mouse button, regardless of whether it
>   is mapped to the left or right logical
>   mouse button. You can determine the
>   system's current mapping of physical
>   mouse buttons to logical mouse buttons
>   by calling
>   GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON).