# Delphi: How can I check if any mouse buttons are pressed - OUTSIDE of a mouse event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a TDrawGrid and want to handle clicking on a cell and scrolling through cells with the mouse wheel slightly differently: When scrolling with the mouse wheel, the view shall center on the selected cell, when simply clicking on a cell, the view shall not move (because that'd be confusing).

Scrolling with the mouse wheel fires the `OnSelectCell` event. Clicking on a cell FIRST fires `OnSelectCell`, followed by `OnMouseDown`. So I need to figure out if `OnSelectCell` was triggered by a mouse click. Easiest way to do (that I can think of) would be to check the current mouse-button state.

`OnSelectCell` doesn't come with any `TMouseButton` or `TShiftState` parameter. So how can I query the mouse-button state?

Comment: Interesting, scrolling with the wheel does not fire OnSelectCell here, selected cell does not change at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `GetKeyState` passing `VK_LBUTTON` to identify the primary mouse button. If the return value is negative, the button was down when the system generated the input message that led to the `OnSelectCell` event being fired.

Comment: +1 for including the "if return val is negative" remark and explanation! :)